# Redis Slave Sync's but does not continue replication

Tags: redis

I have a Redis v3.0.2 Master and Slave

on the slave I issue slaveof (masterIP) 6379

Sync happens, logs looking fine on master and slave. Key counts look sane.

After the sync completes and the slave loads the database, No more operations happen.

running monitor on the master give me hundreds of sets / sec.
the slave only sees a few deletes and an occasional PING

Slave Log:

```
2734:S 16 Aug 07:23:29.460 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Loading DB in memory
2734:S 16 Aug 07:25:16.531 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Finished with success
```

Slave Monitor:

```
~
[119](root@[slave])[0]:\> redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> monitor
OK
1534405063.907020 [0 [master]:6379] "PING"
1534405065.409863 [0 [master]:6379] "DEL" "pmlock12"
1534405065.709784 [0 [master]:6379] "DEL" "pmlock22"
1534405065.909400 [0 [master]:6379] "DEL" "pmlock27"
```

Master Log

```
2951:C 16 Aug 07:20:57.908 * RDB: 279 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
2745:M 16 Aug 07:20:58.297 * Background saving terminated with success
2745:M 16 Aug 07:22:59.369 * Synchronization with slave 10.168.230.15:6379 succeeded
```

Master Monitor:

```
1534405287.136316 [0 [src]:54660] "SET" "CMP36" "{\"m_cur...
1534405252.002731 [0 [src]:45742] "SET" "PM14" "H4sIAAAAAAAAAO1cW4...
```

Master Info

```
[209](root@master)[0]:\> redis-cli info replication
# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:1
slave0:ip=[slave],port=6379,state=online,offset=1747897005,lag=0
master_repl_offset:1748304094
repl_backlog_active:1
repl_backlog_size:104857600
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:1643446495
repl_backlog_histlen:104857600
```

I've rebooted the master and slave, i just can't get the master to send through anything but ping and delete.  I'm not well versed on redis so i'm sure i'm just missing something.

Comment: Slave info replication

# Replication
role:slave
    master_host:[host]
    master_port:6379 
    master_link_status:up
    master_last_io_seconds_ago:0
    master_sync_in_progress:0
    slave_repl_offset:2123664175
    slave_priority:100
    slave_read_only:1
    connected_slaves:0 
    master_repl_offset:0
    repl_backlog_active:0
    repl_backlog_size:104857600
    repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
    repl_backlog_histlen:0